# installing add-on to blender portable, but to the app directory

Tags: add-on

i would like to install an add-on to my blender portable. however when i install it using a downloaded zip via the "install add-on" button, it lands in the local profile folder "AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.81\scripts\addons".
i would like it to land in the folder "BlenderPortable\App\Blender64\2.81\scripts".

how can i do that?

i tried installing it and copying it over to the desired spot, but blender correctly gives me a duplicate error. if i delete the "Roaming" version, the extension is not shown in the list.
any pointers/helps? is there a config file that i can edit manually and point it to the desired folder?

Comment: Try adding it to Blender via the Blender "Portable" add-on file scripts in whatever drive you are using.

Comment: as described above, i already tried, but it does not show up in the add-on list, when i add it to "BlenderPortable\App\Blender64\2.81\scripts". do i have to edit a config file?